# Static Objects part of perm space in GC?

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection

I was reading an article about Java Heap and Garbage Collection, and this was stated: `For the sake of Garbage collection Heap is divided into three main regions named as New Generation, Old or Tenured Generation and Perm space.`

I was wondering where static objects would be kept. I would assume that they are in the perm space. Could anyone clarify?

Comment: AFAIK perm space only keeps class definitions, not instances.

Comment: Perm space is gone as of java 8

Comment: Note that the answer to this depends on the JVM in use. Not all Java implementations work the same way as the Oracle/OpenJDK HotSpot JVM. Another thing to note is that only variables are static - the objects themselves are just like any other object - allocated and placed in the heap.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the comments. It's good to get clarification on this.